# Errors occur during tag dispatch

Tags: c++, type-traits

```
#include <iterator>
#include <forward_list>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<typename C>
using Iterator_type = typename C::iterator;

template<typename Iter>
using Iterator_category = typename iterator_traits<Iter>::iterator_category;

template<typename Ran>
void sort_helper(Ran beg, Ran end, random_access_iterator_tag){
    sort(beg,end);
}

template<typename For>
void sort_helper(For beg, For end, forward_iterator_tag){
    vector<decltype(*beg)> vc{beg, end};
    sort(vc.begin(),vc.end());
    copy(vc.begin(),vc.end(),beg);
}

template<typename C>
void sort(C& c){
    using Iter = Iterator_type<C>;
    sort_helper(c.begin(),c.end(),Iterator_category<Iter>{});
}

void test(vector<string>& vs, forward_list<double>& lls){
    sort(vs);
    sort(lls);
}
```

I get a compile error -- forming pointer to reference type double&

Code from Bjarne Stroustrup -- the C++ programming language 
5.4.2.1 iterator_traits

Comment: [MCVE] dude, errors verbatim please!

Comment: Have you checked the errata? http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following statement:

```
vector<decltype(*beg)> vc{beg, end};
```

the `decltype` specifier yields a reference type (either because it dereferences a pointer that results in an lvalue and itself is an expression, or, because `operator*` from the `For` class-type declares a reference type as its return type) that cannot be stored in a vector. Instead, you should leverage `std::iterator_traits` once again to get the underlying type.

```
vector<typename iterator_traits<For>::value_type> vc{beg, end};
```

Answer (score 2):

From Bjarne's [errata list for the book](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th_printing3.html):

> pg 125: s/decltype(*beg)/Value_type<For>/ reparing the use of decltype would take more space than I have here.

`vector<decltype(*beg)>` tries to create a `vector<double&>`, which is not possible.